# Biblatex footcite on one page only

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, tabularx

Morning,

I'm using biblatex and everything is working fine with one exception. I have tabularx table with dates which I'd like to link to a citation in the footnotes. I've looked at \footcite and while I get the [1] etc beside the text, I'm not seeing the references in the footer. I've also tried \footnote{\cite{theCitation}} to no avail. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{REFERENCES.bib}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{xltabular}% Tabular x cross longtable
\usepackage{caption} % Do a bit more with captions
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, % Colours the links or not
    linkcolor=black, % Colour for internal links
    urlcolor=cyan, % Colour for URLs in the document 
    citecolor=black, % The colour for citations in the document
}
\usepackage{cleveref}



    \begin{table}[H]
        \captionsetup{justification=justified}
        \caption{The caption}
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{c|c|c}
            \hline
            thead{Year} & \thead{A thing} & \thead{Another thing} \\
            \hline
            \hline
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    NEW LINE    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
               THE YEAR\footcite{citationForFootnote} & The thing & The other thing\\
            \hline
            end{tabularx}
        \label{myLabel}
     \end{table}
```

Just to reiterate, the document compiles and everything is sweet, I'd just like to have the references for this table pop up as numbers in the table (on this page only) with the reference in the footnote (which, ideally, would just be the author/year). A regular footnote won't show up either so is it something to do with tabularx?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not tabularx, it is the table environment. floats (and this is also true for non-floating-H-floats) don't let footnotes escape as they add a box around the footnote. From all the footnotes here only the one first survives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,tabularx}
\textheight 5cm
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{X}
tabularx\footnote{tabularx}
\end{tabularx}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{X}
tabularx in table\footnote{tabularx in table}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\mbox{mbox\footnote{mbox}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

That the main reason why `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` exist. So you should use them (or with biblatex `\footnotecitetext`), and yes one has to reset the counter to get the numbers right. Consider to use threeparttable and tablenotes instead -- this will continue to work if you decide to let the table float after all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,tabularx}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\textheight 5cm
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{X}
tabularx in table\footnotemark\\
tabularx in table\footnotemark\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\footcitetext{doody}%
\stepcounter{footnote}%
\footcitetext{herrmann}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, I really need to have a look at the mechanisms behind LaTeX in the background, just always seems a lower priority until something won't work for me! But that's very helpful, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I've just come up with a (less than elegant solution). Using \footnotemark in the table text followed by \footnotetext{\cite{theCitation}} outside the table environment seems to work. Having looked around a bit more I feel this is a tabularx thing correct? If there's a better way than what I'm doing though I'd gladly welcome it.

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside I also had to manually number the footnotes as they were all labelled with the last number (in this case a 6). So this question is still very much open to input from those more capable than I. Cheers!